# SQL Server : UNION with fill NULL value from one of the table columns

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have two SQL Server tables `Table1` and `Table2` defined like this:

Table1:

| Well_id | completion_id | Well_Name | Api_No10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 221 | Well1_Comp1 | Well1 |
| 112 | 222 | Well2_Comp1 | Well2 |
| 113 | 223 | Well3_Comp1 | Well3 |

Table2:

| Well_id | completion_id | Well_Name | Api_No10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 |  | Well1_Comp2 |  |
| 114 |  | Well4_Comp1 |  |
| 115 |  | Well5_Comp1 |  |

`Table1` is the main table and `Table2` rows are being added to `Table1` based on a primary index criteria.

I am able to apply `UNION` to combine the rows from two tables based on a 'defined' `primary_index` column as:

```
WITH Comp_View AS
(
    SELECT
        Well_id, Completion_id, Well_Name, Api_No10,
        CONCAT(Well_Id, '_', Well_Name) AS Primary_Index
    FROM
        table1
),
Pipeline_report AS
(
    SELECT
        Well_id, Completion_id, Well_Name, Api_No10,
        CONCAT(Well_Id,'_',Well_Name) AS Primary_Index
    FROM
        table2
)
SELECT comp.*               
FROM Comp_View comp
UNION
SELECT pipe.*               
FROM Pipeline_report pipe
WHERE Primary_index NOT IN (SELECT Primary_Index FROM Comp_view)
```

I get these results:

[image]

The `table2` has `null` values in the `Api_no10` column. I would like to populate the Api_no10 column in the final table if the '`Wellid`' from `table2` exists in `table1` as well.

In the result set, the `APi_no10` column for the `well_id: 111` with `Primary_index: 111_well1_comp2` should be '`Well1`' but it's `NULL` based on my query.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots, it's impossible to work with for someone else. Use markdown tables

Comment: sure. let me modify those.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a left join to the second half of your union.

```
drop table if exists #Table1, #Table2;
create table #Table1 (Well_id int, completion_id int, Well_Name nvarchar(30), Api_No10 nvarchar(30));
insert into #Table1 (Well_id, completion_id, Well_Name, Api_No10) 
values
    (111,221,'Well1_Comp1','Well1'),
    (112,222,'Well2_Comp1','Well2'),
    (113,223,'Well3_Comp1','Well3');
create table #Table2 (Well_id int, completion_id int, Well_Name nvarchar(30), Api_No10 nvarchar(30));
insert into #Table2 (Well_id, completion_id, Well_Name, Api_No10) 
values
(111,null,'Well1_Comp1',null),
(114,null,'Well4_Comp1',null),
(115,null,'Well5_Comp1',null)

;with Comp_View as
(
    select
        Well_id,
        completion_id,
        Well_Name,
        Api_No10,
        concat(Well_Id,'_',Well_Name) as Primary_Index
    from
        #Table1
),
Pipeline_report as
(
    select
        Well_id,
        completion_id, 
        Well_Name,
        Api_No10,
        CONCAT(Well_Id,'_',Well_Name) as Primary_Index
    from
        #Table2
)

select comp.*               
from Comp_View comp
union
select 
    pipe.Well_id,
    pipe.completion_id,
    pipe.Well_Name,
    isnull(pipe.Api_No10, comp.Api_No10), -- // Gets you the Api_No10 if it available from Table1 but is not in Table2
    pipe.Primary_Index
from 
    Pipeline_report pipe
    left join Comp_View comp
    on pipe.Well_id = comp.Well_id
    and pipe.Well_Name = comp.Well_Name;
```

Results:

| Well_id | completion_id | Well_Name | Api_No10 | Primary_Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | NULL | Well1_Comp1 | Well1 | 111_Well1_Comp1 |
| 111 | 221 | Well1_Comp1 | Well1 | 111_Well1_Comp1 |
| 112 | 222 | Well2_Comp1 | Well2 | 112_Well2_Comp1 |
| 113 | 223 | Well3_Comp1 | Well3 | 113_Well3_Comp1 |
| 114 | NULL | Well4_Comp1 | NULL | 114_Well4_Comp1 |
| 115 | NULL | Well5_Comp1 | NULL | 115_Well5_Comp1 |

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly what you want because the same 'Primary Index' does not exist in both tables.  Do you mean just use the WellId?   Depending on how you link the tables to find the value you want and what the primary keys are, you can do a LEFT JOIN or CROSS APPLY.

LEFT JOIN based on linking with WellId using COALESCE to change nulls to value from other table:

```sql
Pipeline_report as
(
select Well_id,
       Completion_id,
       Well_Name,
       COALESCE(table1.Api_No10, table2.Api_No10) as Api_No10,
       CONCAT(Well_Id,'_',Well_Name) as Primary_Index
from table2
left join table1 on table1.WellId = table2.WellId
)
```

OUTER APPLY using WellId if there are multiple rows to just get one, and using COALESCE to change the null values to the ones from the other table:

```sql
Pipeline_report as
(
select Well_id,
       Completion_id,
       Well_Name,
       COALESCE(table1.Api_No10, t2.Api_No10) as Api_No10,
       CONCAT(Well_Id,'_',Well_Name) as Primary_Index
from table2
outer apply (select top(1) Api_No10
             from table1
             where table1.WellId = table2.WellId) t2
)
```

Comment: You are right.  I modified my statement as: